# Understanding of "git checkout" working with local repo

Tags: git, commit, checkout, git-log

Let's assume I have a repo with file `A.txt`
In remote repo with some commit-id this file contains string `"Hello, World!"`, but I want to clone it to my local machine and change this string to `"Goodbye, World!"`

After `git clone` and `git commit -m "Hello to Goodbye"` I suddenly understand that this is not what I really want to do and trying to return my `"Hello, World!"`

After doing `git checkout -b stable_version <commit-id>` I've got message about 'detached HEAD' state but there are no visible changes for `A.txt` file.

So my question is what exactly should I do for rolling back to `"Hello, World!"`?

Comment: do `git reset <commit-id>` instead. Or `git reset --hard <commit-id>`

Comment: Your checkout command looks good. It should have created the branch `stable_version` on the first revision (if the ID is correct) and you should be there. No reason for you to be in `detached HEAD` at the moment (at least, after the checkout that you have there). Did you run other stuff? Perhaps you should paste the whole set of git commands and their output to tell you what happened more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

try using [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

basically, enter the command `git reset <Your Commit Id>`, and it reverts back to the state before the commit was pushed